# R/Rstudio Frustration - Can't Stop Code Execution

Tags: r, rstudio

I often include `View()` statements in my R scripts. If I accidentally forget the closing bracket at the end of the line, and then run the line of code from the script window using `ctrl-enter`, R just keeps trying to execute the remainder of my script. I don't know why it does that (rather than using the `+` symbol to prompt me to provide further input).

Moreover, I've tried to stop this by setting break points in my code - I can click on the LHS of the page and a little red circle appears. But the breakpoints don't seem to work - R just ignores them and keeps going.

The only way I can get out of it is by killing the process in the Windows task manager and then going back in afterwards. But it's wasting a lot of time.

Does anyone know how I can fix this please?

Thank you.

Comment: The first place would be to make your script syntactically correct, close missing parenthesis and so forth. When I write `View(` in Rstudio, it automatically creates a close bracket so I'm not sure what's going on in your case.

Answer (score 1):

In effect, what your function is processing looks like that:

```
... %>% View(
             lm(am~cyl, mtcars)
             ...
             ...
```

As R can't find the bracket for `)` it includes remaining statements as input to `View` and searches for the bracket.

## Solutions

- Kind of depends on what you want to do with those scripts but if the intention is to run them in the background consider using [`callr`](https://github.com/r-lib/callr#background-r-processes). This package lets you run R from R and offers `kill` methods to kill the process you started that way.
- On Windows pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> should enable you to get back to the console but if it's a memory intense process it may be difficult.
- You may try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in order to kill the process.

Comment: Thank you - I will try these. Do you know why the "red circle" break point isn't working? Is it because R just thinks it is in the middle of the same line of code?

Comment: @Alan Breakpoints work for functions that are sourced as your code is missing closing `)` then I'm guessing that it's newer sourced properly so it won't work in this context.